# Oracle : Buffer Hit Ratio Vs Buffer Cache Hit Ratio

Tags: oracle

can anyone differentiate Buffer Hit Ratio and Buffer Cache Hit Ratio in Oracle database?

Buffer Hit Ratio:

`select CASE WHEN (sum (decode (name,'db block gets', value, 0)) + (sum (decode (name,'consistent gets', value, 0)))) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE trunc ((1- (sum (decode (name,'physical reads', value, 0)) / (sum (decode (name,'db block gets', value, 0)) + (sum (decode(name,'consistent gets', value, 0)))))) * 100) END from v$sysstat`

Buffer Cache Hit Ratio:

`select CASE WHEN (sum (decode (name,'db block gets from cache', value, 0)) + (sum (decode (name,'consistent gets from cache', value, 0)))) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE trunc ((1- (sum (decode (name,'physical reads from cache', value, 0)) / (sum (decode (name,'db block gets from cache', value, 0)) + (sum (decode(name,'consistent gets from cache', value, 0)))))) * 100) END from v$sysstat`

Comment: Who cares?  Either way is a meaningless measure, debunked years ago.

Comment: [Page 7](https://method-r.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Why-You-Should-Focus-on-LIOs-Instead-of-PIOs.pdf). One of many refuting this thing's usefulness. It's not a higher-is-better metric nor is it a lower-is-better metric.

Comment: @JeffHolt You could add an answer and take this opportunity to explain why this metric is not useful. Even if we disagree with the premise of this question, the question can still be useful as a way of explaining the underlying problems to others.

Answer (score 1):

The first ratio measures the cache usage of all reads, and the second ratio measures the cache usage of all reads that tried to read from the cache.

The difference is important because some operations, like parallel reads, often go straight to the data files and won't even try to read from the buffer cache. For example, if you run a query like `select /*+ parallel(16) full(t) */ count(*) from huge_table t`, the first ratio will go down, but the second ratio will stay the same. In many databases, it would be foolish to try to cache the largest tables used for parallel operations, so you might not want to have those operations count against the cache usage.

For more information, here's the relevant section of the [Database Reference Statistics Descriptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/statistics-descriptions-2.html#GUID-2FBC1B7E-9123-41DD-8178-96176260A639):

> consistent gets - Number of times a consistent read was requested for
> a block.
>
> consistent gets direct - Number of times a consistent read
> was requested for a block bypassing the buffer cache (for example,
> direct load operation). This is a subset of "consistent gets"
> statistics value.
>
> consistent gets from cache - Number of times a
> consistent read was requested for a block from buffer cache. This is a
> subset of "consistent gets" statistics value.

I disagree with EdStevens that these ratios are meaningless, but most Oracle professionals would at least agree that these ratios are over-used.

Comment: Sometimes the query I use to get Buffer Hit Ratio returns negative values. Anything wrong with my query shared above @Jon Heller

Comment: @Anna I'm not sure why your query returns a negative number - both queries seem to work fine for me. If it's just a one-time issue you can probably ignore it. Oracle's performance statistics, metrics, and samples are often estimates and the numbers don't always precisely add up.